# JQuery datepicker- 2 inputs From and To

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the Jquery datepicker plugin  with this [timepicker addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) in two input boxes, one for the "From" date and the second with the "To" date.

When I set the first one, I want the second one to be one day after the date selected in the first,disabling all the dates earlier than the date selected in the "From" date

If the "To" date is selected first, then the "From" date is set to the day before the "To" date.

I have found some examples, but I don't know how to get the **date with time**.So,If I  ,for example, select **13**/12/2010 **15:50** in the "From" date, the date in the "To" date is set to **14**/12/2010 **15:50** or at least to **14**/12/2010 **00:00**.

EDITED***

I've just found this [piece of code](http://jsbin.com/iyobi) that works as I want , but without the timepicker addon.

```
 $(function(){

  $('#dateFrom').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         $('#dateTo').datepicker('option','minDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
          }
  });
  $('#dateTo').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         $('#dateFrom').datepicker('option','maxDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    }          
  });

});
```

Based on the above code, would it be possible to adapt it ,so that I can use it with the timepicker addon?

Thanks beforehand

Comment: The problem with using the `onSelect` method is that it does not behave the same way with the datetimepicker plugin.  Notice in your demo that you must click a day to close the widget.  This is not the case with the datetimepicker, probably because of the slider for time.  The fact that there is no reliable event that fires when the user selects a date (either clicks "done" on the plugin or clicks off of the widget) makes it hard to do it this way, at least with the research I've done.

Comment: @Andrew: OK I've decided I'm not going to do anything with those inputs, but there's another page where I also have 2 inputs ( FROM and TO) , there showing a simple calendar is enough, but if I use a this http://jsbin.com/iyobi I get a error in IE. What Should I to make this error disappear?

Comment: I'm not seeing the error on IE8 or IE8 in IE7 mode

Comment: @Andrew: Just try to run the example with the timepicker addon.

Answer (score 1):

I've got most of it, but could not figure out how to set the `hourMin` and `minuteMin` after the widget had already been initialized.  Given the following HTML:

```
<label for="from">From</label><input id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">To</label><input id="to" name="to" />
```

And this JS:

```
$("#from").datetimepicker();
$("#to").datetimepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        var $toDateInput = $("#to");
        var fromDate = $("#from").datetimepicker("getDate");
        var toDate = $toDateInput.datetimepicker("getDate");
        var afterFromDate;

        if (fromDate) {
            if (!toDate || (toDate <= fromDate)) {
                afterFromDate = new Date(fromDate.toUTCString());
                afterFromDate.setDate(afterFromDate.getDate() + 1);               
                $toDateInput.datetimepicker("setDate", afterFromDate);
            }
            $toDateInput.datetimepicker("option", "minDate", fromDate);
        }
    }
});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RWjtL/3/

Most of your criteria are met, but there are a few things that are off:

- When you set the 'To' field blank, the 'From' datepicker's min date is not removed.  I tried setting the `minDate` option to `null` and `""` and got weird behavior.  [Here's a documented issue that could be related](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues#issue/56).
- The `beforeShow` method is called multiple times.  I think this is because of the call to `setDate` inside the handler, but can't be sure.
- As stated above, I could not manage to set `hourMin` and `minuteMin` after the fact, and setting the `minDate` doesn't seem to respect the time part of the date.

The author's [GitHub page](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues) has a list of issues, some of which seem related to the issues I ran into.  Hope that gets you started at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) or [onClose](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onClose) event to change [minDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate) and maxDate options.